# UISearchBar Appearance still shows 1px border when pulled down

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uisearchbar

This is a screenshot while pulling down on the table (which pulls the search bar away from the tabs up top).

[image]

My searchbar is customized via the appearances API.

That 1px border up top remains even though I've set the background image. It varies color depending on the 'style' of the search bar (in this instance I have the search bar set to black opaque).

Any idea how to get rid of it? I've tried setting a clear background color, and trying to change a border color on the layer of the search bar.

Comment: Have you tried making a custom SearchField? I can post an example if you want, I made a whole new one for an app I made as normal appearances didn't really do what I wanted it to.

Comment: I'd rather not. Appearance basically does what I need, minus that pesky little 1px line.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a clean way, but looping through the subviews I found the image view used to create that line. It's frame is (0, -1, 320, 1).

To remove it, I test equality and remove:

```
for (UIView *view in self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews) {
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(CGPointMake(0, -1), view.frame.origin) && CGSizeEqualToSize(view.frame.size, CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1))) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        self.searchBarLineRemoved = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: And let's hope it gets past the App Store guardians! :)

Comment: Should! No private APIs. I've gotten apps through when looping through their subviews.